# How to solve inequasion with double modules?

Tags: inequality, modules

||x+1|-|x-1||<1
Got this from a lection but wasn't able to write it all. all i have in my note is:

1. case of x<=-1 ... 2<1 (aka no solution)
2. case of x>=1 ... 2<1 (aka no solution)
3. x belongs to (-1;1)
   please help, i know that the answer in the third case, just don't know how to check! :(

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: First simplify $|x+1|$, $|x-1|$ and then $||x+1|-|x-1||$, in each of the 3 cases you mention.